# `getBBox()` returning different results for identical DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've got some code that applies text wrapping within SVG, taking a single `<text>` element, and creating multiple `<tspan>` elements within it.

Using this I'm having a problem, in that calling `getBBox()` on 2 elements that I believe are identical is returning different results, and therefore creating a different wrapping effect in 2 circles.

Here's a screenshot to provide some context. This is normally in some overlaid animations, but I've split it out for demonstration purposes. I've got some DOM within which I expect both of the text items to be wrapped in a identical way:

[image]

I've tracked down the problem to a particular part of the code, which follows. A little explanation `textNode` represents a `<tspan>` which is having words amended to it, after each word is added the text is measured using a function called `getScaledBBox()`. If it exceeds the width a new `<tspan>` will be added underneath and the process repeats.

```
// Go through each word to be text wrapped except the first one
(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     word = wordsToWrap[i];

     // If our text goes outside the height boundary, 
     // remove lines until suitable and add an ellipsis through truncate()
     if (getScaledBBox(textNode).height > height) {
         truncate();
         break;

         // Otherwise check if our text goes outside the width boundary. 
         // If so, create an ellipsis
      } else if (getScaledBBox(textNode).width > width) {
         ellipsis();
         break;
      }

      // Debug logging
     console.log("words", textNode.innerHTML, getScaledBBox(textNode), textNode.getBBox());

     let node = textNode;
     while(Array.from(node.classList).indexOf("planet-group") === -1) {
          node = node.parentNode;
     }
     console.log("html", node.parentNode.innerHTML);
 }

 placeWord(word);
}
```

The particular problem I'm having is that `getScaledBBox()` is returning different values, when the `<tspan>`s it's operating seem identical as far as I can tell.

```
export const getScaledBBox = (node) => {
    const devicePixelRatio = window ? window.devicePixelRatio || 1 : 1;
    const boundingBox = node.getBBox();
    const height = boundingBox.height / devicePixelRatio;
    const width = boundingBox.width / devicePixelRatio;
    return { height, width };
};
```

Here's some output from my console logging (note that `width` and `height` are defined as 280, 140 respectively for both). For the first (black) run which works:

```
<tspan x="-140px" dx="140px" dy="44px" dominant-baseline="alphabetic" style="baseline-shift: 0%;">TH</tspan> {height: 48, width: 52.38125}   
<tspan x="-140px" dx="140px" dy="44px" dominant-baseline="alphabetic" style="baseline-shift: 0%;">TH test</tspan> {height: 48, width: 130.23125} 
<tspan x="-140px" dx="140px" dy="44px" dominant-baseline="alphabetic" style="baseline-shift: 0%;">TH test save</tspan> {height: 48, width: 222.5375}
```

For the second (orange) circle I get:

```
<tspan x="-140px" dx="140px" dy="44px" dominant-baseline="alphabetic" style="baseline-shift: 0%;">TH</tspan> {height: 19.7875, width:
20.94375}
<tspan x="-140px" dx="140px" dy="44px" dominant-baseline="alphabetic" style="baseline-shift: 0%;">TH test</tspan> {height: 19.7875, width: 52.35}  
<tspan x="-140px" dx="140px" dy="44px" dominant-baseline="alphabetic" style="baseline-shift: 0%;">TH test save</tspan> {height: 19.7875, width: 89.3125}
```

As you can see from the logging at the end, the values are completely different. The interesting thing is they are exactly a factor of 2.5 out, which is the value of `window.devicePixelRatio`, however `getScaledBBox()` takes that into account already, and is the same code path for both spans.

I've also logged the HTML to see if anything was different, as the wrapping code for one of these runs about 500ms after the other due to specifically introduce delays. This yields:

After the 1st word this is the DOM for the working black circle
[image]

After the 1st word this is the DOM for the failing orange circle
[image]

Can anyone see what I might be missing, that could cause the bounds to be calculated incorrectly? Unfortunately I've not managed to get a standalone reproduction yet.

Comment: There can be several reasons for this, without seeing the production script..I would at least start from console logging `window.devicePixelRatio` within the getScaledBBox. It might be that you are dynamically resizing your viewport in an onload event or something and that value changes. The fact that you are appending the second node after 500ms is a hint to that. devicePixelRatio should never change but just try to eliminate.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are using `devicePixelRatio` anyway. Why not just do all your calculations in SVG units?

Comment: @ibowankenobi sure, I've actually done that already and confirm that the `devicePixelRatio` doesn't change.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I believe `getBBox()` is doing exactly that? According to the spec it's measuring content in the SVG co-ordinate system: _Returns the tight bounding box in current user space (i.e., after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) on the geometry of all contained graphics elements_

Comment: @PaulLeBeau sorry I should add, given that information our constrained width and height would be incorrect as they don't take the scaling into account. I guess another way would have been to multiply the width/height constraints by the `devicePixelRatio`... However if I call just the regular `getBBox()` the values are still out by the factor of 2.5

Comment: Couple of more things, I can see that the outermost g has a scale(0,0), this will not change anything on the getBBox but it tells me that you are doing some force-field animations/zoom etc that is ongoing. If during these transitions you are dynamically updating the textContent of the text element, the getBBox should be recalled. A second question is I wonder what would getComputedTextLength would return, is it different as well? A third (unrelated) question is what does getCTM return both cases?

Comment: @ibowankenobi you're correct that there's a transition that happens on the outer `<g>`. I'll disable that to confirm whether it makes a difference, however both elements are in the same `<g>` so I'd hope there's no effect. I'll go try calling `getComputedTextLength` and update the question

Comment: @ibowankenobi So a really interesting discovery off the back of that. `getComputedTextLength` is returning almost exactly 52 for both. However taking the transform off the outer `<g>` on startup prevents the text on the black circle from wrapping correctly too... I don't understand why yet though

Comment: The behavior you are observing is happening because although getComputedTextLength should work just like getBBox, meaning that is ignores the upstream transforms, it does not for very small values. for values like scale(0.01,0.01) on the parent g, it will still give a constant textLength, if you fall below this, it'll decrease until 1e-6, if you put exactly 0 than it will suddenly display even a larger value. Since you are starting from 0 scale in the parent g, I guess this is the culprit. Start from a more reasonable value like scale(1e-2,1e-2). Did you also check the getCTM?

Comment: @ibowankenobi are you ok to chat briefly in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171341/q50409781 ? I don't quite follow